# Flutter Desktop App (MacOS) - Unable to find SQLITE DB and creates empty db in MacOS /Users/<user>/Documents directory

Tags: flutter, macos, dart, sqflite, flutter-desktop

There's some very odd problems when using flutter for MacOs apps.

I'm using the following Database initialisation:

```
 _initDatabase() async {
Directory dbDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String path = join(dbDirectory.path, _databaseName);
//ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/mydatabase.sqlite");
//List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
//await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);
return await openDatabase(path,
    version: _databaseVersion,
    //onCreate: _onCreate
    );}
```

What is the issue?

I keep on getting error that it cannot find the table. The table absolutely exists.
But then I checked the logs and it appears it is using the /Users/myname/Documents to store the database file.

that's not what I want. The database file for this application is in the assets folder, and it should remain (when it is packaged) within the app bundle.

How do I specify the assets folder??
What am I doing wrong??

The create function, by the way, isn't working either.

```
Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
await db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE $table (
        $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        $col1 TEXT,
        $col2 TEXT,
        $col3 TEXT
      )
      ''');}
```

Im exhausted from trying...

Comment: `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` is `$HOME/Documents` on Mac, so that would be where the database ends up with the code you've supplied. I really *cannot* state what a bad idea it is to attempt to create a writeable database in the assets folder - it should be considered read-only. If you want to make it in a private location, then some place like `getApplicationSupportDirectory()` might make more sense.

Comment: Thank you Petesh. I will change my code to use getApplicationSupportDirectory() - sure. But why can't it find the table anyway - even if its in the getApplicationDocumentDirectory()? And why is it copying the database to the $HOME/Documents directory as an empty sqlite file? That DB has many tables in there.

Comment: Possibly the lack of a `flush=true` on the `writeAsBytes()` method in the commented out code? It should create a database file from the sqlite content based on what you've written.